# Why does the first alert trigger multiple times after the alert conditions have been met with a reset in it

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, indicator

Why does it trigger multiple times after the alert conditions have been met for the alertcondition(confirmed_signal, title="Price crosses upper range with confirmation", message="Price has crossed the upper range with confirmation") ?

I am using the `lower_range_confirmed` as confirmation for the alert when it cross upper range so that if lower range is my exit the alert would need to go back to exit and confirm before a second short trigger.

```
var lower_range_confirmed = false

if close < offset1

    lower_range_confirmed := true

//alert condition for the second VWAP (upper range) with confirmation

price2 = close

confirmed_signal = price2 > offset2 and lower_range_confirmed

alertcondition(confirmed_signal, title="Price crosses upper range with confirmation", message="Price has crossed the upper range with confirmation")

// Reset the confirmation flag after the lower range trigger

if confirmed_signal

    lower_range_confirmed := false
```

Answer (score 0):

Anytime `close < offset1` is `true`, you reset your flag. This could happen multiple times during a bar's lifetime.

You can add `barstate.isconfirmed` to your condition to make it non-repaint. With that, it will only execute your alert when the bar is closed (last update).

Answer (score 0):

```
if confirmed_signal
    alert('your message here', alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
```

Comment: Yes you can use  alert.freq_once_per_bar, but you will receive alert at the first time of your condition at the bar, but when the bar close your condition may change and it might be changed many times per bar, I recommend to use alert.freq_once_per_bar_close, it's more reliable and more correct. I always use and check all conditions in my scripts at closed bars.

Answer (score 0):

incase anybody also needs an answer the answer is acturally use varip  instead of var

also change from alertcondition to this type

```
if confirmed_signal
    alert('your message here', alert.freq_all)
```